# How do I iterate inside a queryset in django template

Tags: python, django, jinja2

My django view returns a dictionary `people` with values for all keys in list format.
The code for the view is:

```
class ProjectDetail(View):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
        roles = Role.objects.filter(project=pk)
        people = {}
        for role in roles:
            try:
                people[role] += Person.objects.filter(role=role.pk)
            except KeyError:
                people[role] = [Person.objects.filter(role=role.pk)]

        context = {
            'project': project,
            'people': people
        }

        return render(request, 'project_management/project_detail.html', context)
```

My Models

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    introduction = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Role(models.Model):
    role_name =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In order to iterate through the dictionary I used:

```
{% for designation, persons in people.items %}
<h5> {{ designation.role_name }} </h5>
<ul>
    {% for person in persons %} <!-- My Problem lies here, this loop is not iterating, it's running only once-->
        <li> {{person}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The result I got is:

[image]

I want the items inside queryset listed out separately, instead of being shown inside square brackets. How can I make that happen?

Comment: Share your models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do all this work. You can pass only the `project`. For example with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ProjectDetail(View):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'project_management/project_detail.html', {'project': project})
```

or even simpler with a [**`DetailView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView):

```
class ProjectDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Status.objects.prefetch_related(
        'role_set', 'role_set__person_set'
    )
    template_name = 'project_management/project_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'project'
```

Then in the template you can render this with:

```
{% for role in project.role_set.all %}
<h5> {{ role.role_name }} </h5>
<ul>
    {% for person in role.person_set.all %}
        <li> {{ person.name }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know all this could be done so easily at once. Also, it'd be very helpful of you if you could tell if there is a similar way to create an update view for all these models at once, using a single class?

Comment: @theCursedPirate: no, Django's `CreateView` and `UpdateView` focus on creating/updating a record of a single model. Usually class-based views are designed for quite simple tasks that are very common, and thus abstracts away boilerplate logic.